# Factory method for objects - best practice?

Tags: python, coding-style, decorator, class-method, factory-method

This is a question regarding the best practice for creating an instance of a class or type from different forms of the same data using python. Is it better to use a class method or is it better to use a separate function altogether? Let's say I have a class used to describe the size of a document. (Note: This is simply an example. I want to know the best way to create an instance of the class **not** the best way to describe the size of a document.)

```
class Size(object):
    """
    Utility object used to describe the size of a document.
    """

    BYTE = 8
    KILO = 1024

    def __init__(self, bits):
        self._bits = bits

    @property
    def bits(self):
        return float(self._bits)

    @property
    def bytes(self):
        return self.bits / self.BYTE

    @property
    def kilobits(self):
        return self.bits / self.KILO

    @property
    def kilobytes(self):
        return self.bytes / self.KILO

    @property
    def megabits(self):
        return self.kilobits / self.KILO

    @property
    def megabytes(self):
        return self.kilobytes / self.KILO
```

My `__init__` method takes a size value represented in bits (bits and only bits and I want to keep it that way) but lets say I have a size value in bytes and I want to create an instance of my class. Is it better to use a class method or is it better to use a separate function altogether?

```
class Size(object):
    """
    Utility object used to describe the size of a document.
    """

    BYTE = 8
    KILO = 1024

    @classmethod
    def from_bytes(cls, bytes):
        bits = bytes * cls.BYTE
        return cls(bits)
```

OR

```
def create_instance_from_bytes(bytes):
    bits = bytes * Size.BYTE
    return Size(bits)
```

This may not seem like an issue and perhaps both examples are valid but I think about it every time I need to implement something like this. For a long time I have preferred the class method approach because I like the organisational benefits of tying the class and the factory method together. Also, using a class method preserves the ability to create instances of any subclasses so it's more object orientated. On the other hand, a friend once said "When in doubt, do what the standard library does" and I am yet to find an example of this in the standard library.

Comment: I'd flip a coin. Most python libraries seem to prefer procedural APIs, but that's because they're meant to be consumed in a different way from reusable code that's internal to your codebase.

Comment: PS, don't call a variable `bytes`; that's a builtin type (in 2.6 and later).

Comment: And of course I just realized that I made the same mistake in my answer: `Size(bytes=20)`. Don't do as I do, do as I say. :)

Comment: Bad variable name `bytes` duly noted. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 36):

First, most of the time you think you need something like this, you don't; it's a sign that you're trying to treat Python like Java, and the solution is to step back and ask why you need a factory.

Often, the simplest thing to do is to just have a constructor with defaulted/optional/keyword arguments. Even cases that you'd never write that way in Java—even cases where overloaded constructors would feel wrong in C++ or ObjC—may look perfectly natural in Python. For example, `size = Size(bytes=20)`, or `size = Size(20, Size.BYTES)` look reasonable. For that matter, a `Bytes(20)` class that inherits from `Size` and adds absolutely nothing but an `__init__` overload looks reasonable. And these are trivial to define:

```
def __init__(self, *, bits=None, bytes=None, kilobits=None, kilobytes=None):
```

Or:

```
BITS, BYTES, KILOBITS, KILOBYTES = 1, 8, 1024, 8192 # or object(), object(), object(), object()
def __init__(self, count, unit=Size.BITS):
```

But, sometimes you *do* need factory functions. So, what do you do then? Well, there are two kinds of things that are often lumped together into "factories".

A `@classmethod` is the idiomatic way to do an "alternate constructor"—there are examples all over the stdlib—`itertools.chain.from_iterable`, `datetime.datetime.fromordinal`, etc.

A function is the idiomatic way to do an "I don't care what the actual class is" factory. Look at, e.g., the built-in `open` function. Do you know what it returns in 3.3? Do you care? Nope. That's why it's a function, not `io.TextIOWrapper.open` or whatever.

Your given example seems like a perfectly legitimate use case, and fits pretty clearly into the "alternate constructor" bin (if it doesn't fit into the "constructor with extra arguments" bin).

Comment: While I agree with this - it's only fair to point out that another design choice instead of a @classmethod - is to make `__init__(kilobytes=345)` etc...

Comment: @JonClements: Good point—although I think that really fits in with the first sentence, that definitely isn't clear as written, so I'll edit it.

Comment: Yup - what I was thinking for this use-case: http://dpaste.com/958194/ (except that it should be n * base *cough*)

Comment: @JonClements: The last time I saw "56 kilobits" and "use case" in the same context, it was about the need to download progressive JPG files of TV starlets more quickly. :)

Comment: Okay, so it seems like the best practice is to avoid it where possible. My next question is probably more to do with static methods as opposed to to class methods but it is fairly closely related to this question. I thank you both for your helpful feed back and I would appreciate it if you could take a look at the next question and comment on whether I am cleaning up my code in an appropriate fashion. (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017734/using-static-methods-in-python-best-practice)

Comment: What happens when someone tries `Size(bits=5, bytes=20)`? Seems like you end up having to write a bunch of conditional logic and exception throwing which you could otherwise avoid. In any case, a more interesting example would be one where something as simple as `unit` isn't sufficient. Specifically, a case where the structure of the input is significantly different.